# How to estimate a regression with both variables i and t simultaneously

Tags: r, regression

I want to estimate a regression for a variable, LWAGE (log wage), against EXP (years of work experience). The data that I have has participants tracked across 7 years, so each year their number of years of work experience increases by 1.

When I do the regression for

= 0 + 1 +

I used

```
reg1 <- lm(LWAGE~EXP, data=df)
```

Now I'm trying to do the following regression:

= 0 + 1 + i.

But I'm not sure how to include my the time based component into my regression. I searched around but couldn't find anything relevant.

Comment: It seems you need a panel data approach.

Comment: does that mean doing seperate regressions for each year in question and then comparing each regression? (so in my case doing 7 separate regressions)

Comment: You can extract time effects with a panel data approach.

Answer (score 1):

Are you attempting to include time-fixed effects in your model or an interaction between your variable EXP and time (calling this TIME for this demonstration)?

For time fixed effects using lm() you can just include time as a variable in your model. Time should be a factor.

```
reg2 <- lm(LWAGE~EXP + TIME, data = df)
```

As an interaction between EXP and TIME it would be

```
reg3 <- lm(LWAGE~EXP*TIME, data = df)
```

Based on your description it sounds like you might be looking for the interaction. I.e. How does the effect of experience on log of wages vary by time?

You can also take a look at the plm package for working with panel data.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plm/vignettes/plmPackage.html

Comment: Thankyou very much for your answer 

reg2 <- lm(LWAGE~EXP + TIME, data = df)

Is exactly what I was looking for.